# Compute the given integral with residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Problem is $\int_{|z| = \pi}\tan nz dz , (n \in N)$

Ans: $-4i\pi$

from the theorem, i got $\int_{|z| = \pi}\tan nz dz = 2i\pi \big[res(f,\frac \pi{2n}) + res(f,-\frac \pi{2n}) \big]$

Computing it...

($\cos nz$ at $z = \frac \pi{2n}$ is $0$, and $(\cos nz)' = -n \sin nz$ is not 0, so we can take derivative)
$$res\bigg(f,\frac \pi{2n}\bigg) =\frac {\sin nz}{(\cos nz)'} = \frac {\sin nz}{-n\sin nz} = - \frac 1n$$
Also for $z = -\frac \pi{2n}$
$$res\bigg(f,-\frac \pi{2n}\bigg) = - \frac 1n$$

And final  $$\int_{|z| = \pi}\tan nz dz = - \frac {4i\pi}{n}$$

where is my mistake?

Comment: We have poles at $z_k=\frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi $ for each $k$ with $-n\leq k\leq  n-1$

Comment: oh thats right. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the other poles: $\frac{3\pi}{2n},-\frac{3\pi}{2n},\ldots$

Comment: How does $\frac {\pi}n$ is a pole for $\tan xn$?

Comment: @SpikeBughdaryan I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Yes i got it, thanks